# How to use whatsapp messenger in androvm?

Tags: android, mx-linux

I am trying to use whatsapp in androvm and when I open the application instead of asking for my mobile number, it shows me the QR code that appears in whatsapp web.

I have tried with older versions of whatsapp and I have changed the date on the android in the virtual machine to try to register and the option to enter my mobile number has appeared, but when I click next to send the code, it gets stuck and it does not work.

Apparently the latest versions of whatsapp have blacklisted androvm.

The truth is that I only need whatsapp in linux without using a QR code, or having a nearby cell phone configured with whatsapp.

I have tried whatsapp web and whatsapp desktop from flatpak and nothing after a few days asks for a QR code again (the session started is not maintained).

Any brilliant solution? Nothing else occurs to me.

Comment: Uh, did androvm not basically stop existing around 10 years ago? Are versions of android supported by a 2012 emulator still supported by Whatsapp?

Comment: "*it shows me the QR code that appears in whatsapp web.*" AFAIK, that's how WhatsApp works on Android "tablets" (i.e. big screen) currently.

Comment: My dad has a tablet that does not have a sim card and whatsapp messenger when he opens it asks him to enter his number, just like on his cell phone. And in windows I tried with the nox emulator and it's the same, it asks for the number. So it seems to me that it is not the expected behavior for whatsapp messenger.

Comment: marcus muller Androvm is the best way to emulate android on linux in my opinion. Genymotion is slower to start and you have to have the proprietary driver installed to use it; which in the case of nvidia is a headache. The android version is old 4.4.1, but almost any app runs there. I even have a google app (an old version) but it works the same to see news of my interest from PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The reason why whatsapp messenger does not work on androvm is that the latest whatsapp updates have, so to speak, a series of phone models approved to use the platform.

When whatapp verified the model, it realized that it was not a model recognized by whatsapp. This is the default model:

> androVM for VirtualBox ('Tablet' version).

The solution is to change the android model. This is how it's working for me:

1. edit file /system/build.prop in androvm
2. find all properties named ro.product... and replace their values ​​with another standard android model.

The values ​​of these default properties are:

```
ro.product.model=androVM for VirtualBox ('Tablet' version)
ro.product.brand=generic
ro.product.name=vbox86t
ro.product.device=vbox86t
ro.product.board=
ro.product.cpu.abi=x86
ro.product.manufacturer=unknown
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
```

In my case, look in a virtual machine called nox in windows and look for these values. The nox emulator on windows pretended to be a samsung. Copy these values ​​and put them to androvm. Then restart (if the system does not restart, it does not take the values) and walaa when I entered whatsapp messenger it already showed me to authenticate with my phone number and I did it and that's it I can use whatapp messenger in a light virtual machine like androvm.

note: To edit these values ​​it is necessary to be root, although androvm already comes as root and also have a root file explorer. I used FX from playstore and installed its plugin for root. Although this file can be edited in different ways.

This solution is broad. It can also work for cell phones that WhatsApp has on the black list. You change the model and ready you can use whatsapp. Although in other versions higher than android 4.1.1 it may be necessary to use xposed installer.apk and device faker to simulate another android device.

Anyway, I hope this good solution for me can help you.

**warning: only change values ​​that have ro.product. If you change other values, you may throw away the virtual machine or system on your android cell phone. Anyway make a backup**

**Edited:** If you have a cell phone with a camera, you can temporarily configure whatsapp on it, then install **whatsie** in mxlinux. There it will ask you for the QR code. Use the cell phone to authenticate in whatsie with the QR code. Then you can configure another phone number on the cell phone, deleting the cache of the WhatsApp application, but WhatsApp will already be working.

whatsie is better than the other apps. I am using it and I have been using it for more than two weeks and the session has not been closed.

I used my dad's tablet, I cleared the WhatsApp cache and set my number, I authenticated with WhatsApp and then cleared the cache again and set my dad's number on the tablet again. Although a better method would be to duplicate the WhatsApp app.